# Will the Artemis I SLS do a static fire on the pad following rollout?

Tags: sls, ssme, artemis-program

Following the rollout for the Artemis I wet dress rehearsal, or the rollout for launch, will the core stage perform a static fire on the pad?

Answer (score 6):

None is planned. The troubled "[green run](https://spacenews.com/nasa-performs-full-duration-sls-green-run-static-fire-test/)" tests in 2021 were the only planned firings of the stage before launch (and only one was planned, the second one was a do-over).

This [NASA page](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-fully-stacked-for-moon-mission-readies-for-artemis-i) lists the steps in the launch campaign from stacking to launch. Here is a summary.

- Interface Verification Testing
- Program Specific Engineering Testing
- End-to-End Communications Testing
- Countdown Sequencing Testing
- Wet Dress Rehearsal Testing

While the last one sounds promising, it is only a fueling test, with no firing planned.

This is similar to a Shuttle launch campaign in that "[flight readiness firings](https://www.americaspace.com/2015/09/19/firing-up-the-shuttle-looking-back-at-the-flight-readiness-firings-part-1/)" on the pad only took place when a new Orbiter was stacked for the first time, or if there was some other compelling reason (7 were done throughout the program).